# How can I show notifications to the users at the date they have provided store at Cloud Firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-local-notification

Suppose I have collection in Cloud Firestore name 'notifications' and collections 'notifications' have many docs and each docs has List of dates in the form of List of String which to can later convert into DateTime by the help of .toDate() and those dates are provided by users itself and store in Cloud Firestore .How can I push local notifications to all the dates in every docs at the time of 6 pm ?
I hope my question is clear to you If doubt you can ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use cloud functions and setup a cron to run after n seconds/ minutes

Comment: @griffins can you please explain it in brief